# Black dot on circuit diagram

Tags: pcb, diagram

[image: Black dot on circuit diagram]

See black dot on "OUT". Is it a junction or does it mean something else? This is the only black dot on the diagram, despite it having multiple splits and junctions elsewhere in the circuit.

So my oven just broke. The OUT connector (in grey) looked chipped, possibly from a short. This is what it look like in real life. The camera angle might not show it, but I think the connection is same as the IN below.

[image: Chipped "OUT"]

A different angle:

[image: different angle]

Comment: I think it's either an error in the drawing or it corresponds with a marking on the terminal block it represents.

Comment: Is it possible IN is female (i.e. a socket) and OUT is male (i.e. a pin)?

Comment: @DerStrom8 post edited. the OUT looks the same as the IN, other than its broken.

Comment: Well there is a box and hatching around the OUT terminal.

Comment: it may be emphasizing that the terminal can be dangerous because it is switched ... measuring it may show no line voltage, but beware

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The black dot most likely represents the terminal with the black silkscreen outline on the PCB, the designers wanted people to make sure 'out' pin gets special attention and demarcation.

I've done this for service people in documentation to make sure they 'don't screw up' polarity (and sometimes they still do)

It also appears that the terminal is even a different color for this purpose .

If you didn't plug the common terminal of the heaters into 'out', it could be really bad. It probably won't matter as much if you got BA and BR swapped.